# Django - Update field value after 7 days with Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

My today Question is how i can change value of field after 7 days using Celery

My models:

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    availability_free_users = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=7))
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

So i want to update availability to true if today date (only date not hour) = availability_free_users

Answer (score 1):

First, that default won't do what you're expecting. It'll be run once at load time. You'll need to turn it into a separate function and pass the function itself to default (lambda works here but is apparently not recommended based on what I've read).

As far as celery, you can set up a [`celery beat`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) task run (daily or whatever suits your purposes) that queries for Episodes that are due to be marked available and haven't been, then marks them available.

Note that you could do that entirely with one queryset filter and update chain, but if you do, any signals you have on this model will not be triggered. For that to happen you'd need to iterate over the queryset and save the change directly on each model.